# How can I achieve similar functionality as BlockingCollection in TPL?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library

I have created a simple class that contains a BlockingCollection. It represents a queue of actions that will be executed in the order in which they were received. I have read a lot of articles about TPL and it seems like I should be using that instead of what I'm using currently. One reason would be that unit testing would be easier and also less code would be written as well. I know that you can easily spin up new tasks using Task.Factory.StartNew() and such, but not sure how I can use that in a similar fashion as the class I currently have. How can I accomplish the same thing with TPL?

As requested, here is the class that I created:

```
public class MyService
{
    /// <summary>Queue of actions to be consumed on a separate thread</summary>
    private BlockingCollection<MyObject> queue = new BlockingCollection<MyObject>();

    public MyService()
    {
        StartService();
    }

    public void AddToQueue(MyObject newObject)
    {
        queue.Add(newObject);
    }

    private void StartService()
    {
        System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            while (true)
            {
                try
                {
                    MyObject myObject = queue.Take(); // blocks until new object received

                    // Do work...
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    // Log...
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Be careful with `StartNew`, if you don't use it correctly [you could have code running on the UI thread when you don't expect it to](http://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/08/startnew-is-dangerous.html), use  `Task.Run(` instead unless you have a specific reason to use `StartNew`. Also, to give you a general nudge in the direction (I don't know if this is what you need) but look in to [TPL DataFlow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Could you give an example of code that you want to do?

Comment: I just added code to make it more clear.

Comment: Take @ScottChamberlain on his advice and look into TPL dataflow. It allows you to build a pipeline to push your data through and looks like it would solve your issue.

Comment: Not too sure what you're looking for, but wouldn't a `ConcurrentQueue` do the trick? It's a FIFO collection and thread-safe... or does the collection need to remain persistent?

Comment: Looking at your updated code, you are using `StartNew` incorrectly (you do not pass in a `TaskSchedueller`). I recommend you read that blog post I linked to in my first comment or switch to `Task.Run(`. Also, since you are using `BlockingCollection` you might want to look in to it's [`GetConsumingEnumerable()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287186(v=vs.110).aspx) method. That lets you replace your `while(true)` with `foreach(MyObject myObject in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())`.

Comment: @code4life a `BlockingCollection` uses `ConcurrentQueue` by default as it's underlying collection.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain Using `GetConsumingEnumerable()` means that after that call the blocking collection is readonly, no more items can be added. I don't think that is what the OP wants. Using `.Take()` seems fine to me in this case.

Comment: @Maarten No it does not. You can keep adding items. Calling `GetEnumerator()` makes a readonly snapshot of the data, but the consuming version will process new data as it shows up. If no data is available it blocks till a new item is added, if you call `CompleteAdding()` once the collection is empty it will exit the `foreach` loop. Perhaps you wher thinking of `CompleteAdding()`? That prevents new items from being added once you call it

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I think so, my apologies.

Comment: Thanks everyone, I will look into your suggestions.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain `foreach(MyObject myObject in queue.GetConsumingEnumerable())`works, but I think an enumerator that blocks is confusing for quite a lot of people, so I would stay away from it. The `while` pattern does exactly the same thing and is not much longer, so I would use that instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BlockingCollection` and async collections family created to easy producer-consumer scenarios. (For example one writer and multiple readers)

Sure - you can manage to build almost the same with `Task.Run` that will add, remove, clean, etc.. items to non synchronized collection like `List<T>` but then you have to manage all multi-threading issues by yourself (and there's a lot of issues).

For example:

```
public class MyService
{
    /// <summary>Queue of actions to be consumed on a separate thread</summary>
    private BlockingCollection<MyObject> queue = new BlockingCollection<MyObject>();
    private IEnumerable<Task> readers = Enumerable.Range(0, 10).Select((t) => new Task(() => this.StartService()));

public MyService()
{
    StartService();
    readers.AsParallel().ForAll(t => t.Start());
}

public void AddToQueue(MyObject newObject)
{
    queue.Add(newObject);
}

private void StartService()
{
        while (true)
        {
            try
            {
                MyObject myObject = queue.Take(); // blocks until new object received

                // Do work...
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                // Log...
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You see - there's multiple 'reader' on the same collection. If you have done `BlockingCollection` yourself you should handle all `lock`s around collection, etc..

Comment: So it's better to use BlockingCollection in this case then?

Comment: @Andrew Yes. This answer gives you an example with multiple consumers, your code has a single consumer. If you only need a single consumer, your code is just fine. Maybe a cancellation token if you want to be able to shut down the service.

Comment: It suggested to use `BlockingCollection` (and variants) in multi-threaded scenarios

Answer (score 0):

Old fashion, blocking synchronization and task-based asynchronism don't mix very well.

```
Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // some thing that sometimes blocks
        }
    });
```

is only a fancy way of writing

```
new Thread(() =>
   {
      while (true)
      {
          // some thing that sometimes blocks
      }
});
```

Both of these will occupy a thread for virtually forever. The first  one will use one from the  thread pool, which should be better than a specially created one, but as it never ever releases it later, the benefits disappear.

If you want to use tasks and the TPL, and get benefits from it, you should avoid as much as possible anything that blocks. You could for instance use a `ConcurrentQueue` as your backing queue and do something like this:

```
public class MyService
{
    /// <summary>Queue of actions to be consumed by separate task</summary>
    private ConcurrentQueue<MyObject> queue = new ConcurrentQueue<MyObject>();

    private bool _isRunning = false;
    private Task _consumingTask;

    public MyService()
    {
    }

    public void AddToQueue(MyObject newObject)
    {
        queue.Add(newObject);
    }

    private void StartService()
    {
        _isRunning = true;
        Task.Run( async () =>
        {
            while (_isRunning )
            {
                MyObject myObject;

                while(_isRunning && queue.TryDequeue(out myObject)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        // Do work...
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // Log...
                    }
                }
                await Task.Delay(100); // tune this value to one pertinent to your use case 
            }
        });
    }

    public void StopService()
    {
        _isRunning = false;
        _consumingTask.Wait();
    }
}
```

This implementation never blocks and only occupies a thread when computation are really needed. It's also very easy to mix other `Task` with it gracefully.

TLDR: if you go the `Task` way, go all the way. The middle point is really not where you want to be, you will get all the complexity and none of the advantages.